# Ubuntu/14.04 / Apache2 configuration issues? Not sure what I am doing wrong Laravel: default route will render but others will not.

Tags: server, apache2, .htaccess

Laravel will render the default /  root page normally. but will not render default routes or error pages. 
My web browser will return with Apache (NOT Laravel) error pages with I try and access /test

Here is some info (please let me know if you need more detail)

Server Directory Tree

```
/var/www/
└── html
    ├── access.log
    ├── app
    ├── artisan
    ├── bootstrap
    ├── composer.json
    ├── composer.lock
    ├── config
    ├── database
    ├── error.log
    ├── gulpfile.js
    ├── package.json
    ├── phpspec.yml
    ├── phpunit.xml
    ├── public
    ├── readme.md
    ├── resources
    ├── server.php
    ├── storage
    ├── tests
    └── vendor
```

Views (test view is copy of the default welcome view)

```
/var/www/html/resources/views/
├── errors
│   └── 503.blade.php
├── test.blade.php
├── vendor
└── welcome.blade.php
```

Routes

```
<?php    

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});    


Route::get('test', function () {
    return view('test');
});    


Route::get('anotherTest', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    

    # The location of our projects public directory.
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/public    

    # Useful logs for debug.
    CustomLog       /var/www/html/access.log common
    ErrorLog        /var/www/html/error.log    

    # Rewrites for pretty URLs, better not to rely on .htaccess.
    <Directory /www/var/html>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>    

</VirtualHost>
```

using default (provided) .htaacess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>    

    RewriteEngine On    

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]    

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also my error log is empty 
But access log  shows 404 and 496

```
admini@linux:/var/www/html$ cat error.log
admini@linux:/var/www/html$ cat access.log
192.168.1.130 - - [24/Jul/2015:15:51:53 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1448
192.168.1.130 - - [24/Jul/2015:15:54:46 -0700] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 496
192.168.1.130 - - [24/Jul/2015:15:56:37 -0700] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 496
192.168.1.130 - - [24/Jul/2015:15:57:11 -0700] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 496
192.168.1.130 - - [24/Jul/2015:15:57:13 -0700] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 495
192.168.1.130 - - [24/Jul/2015:16:14:53 -0700] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 496
192.168.1.130 - - [24/Jul/2015:16:14:53 -0700] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 495
192.168.1.130 - - [24/Jul/2015:16:18:16 -0700] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 496
192.168.1.130 - - [24/Jul/2015:16:18:17 -0700] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 404 495
admini@linux:/var/www/html$
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing my Apache config file to the below resolved the issue.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName somehost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public    

    CustomLog       /var/www/html/access.log common
    ErrorLog        /var/www/html/error.log    

   <Directory /var/www/html/public>
      <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options -MultiViews
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: By apache  config file you mean `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`?